# Using a python script with VB .NET

Tags: python-3.x, vb.net

so i ma creating a pdf to jpeg program and need to make a GUI in order for someone to enter the pdf file they want to convert. I am wondering have i can have a python script interact with VB .NET so that the user can put in a location of the file and then the script will take that string from VB .NET and convert the file.

I have the python code that converts the file i just need to implement it into VB .NET or find another way to make a GUI in little time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I found out that python supports command line argumennts.
Well, here's how to pass arguments to python from Visual Basic.

In a Visual Basic project, create a new `Form` - name `Form1`.

Add a `Button` and a `TextBox` to the Form and add the following code:

```
Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim p As New Process
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = TextBox1.Text
        p.StartInfo.FileName = "script.py"   '"script.py" must be in the debug folder'
        p.Start()
    End Sub
End Class
```

I wrote a python script `script.py` just for this example which contains

```
import sys

print(sys.argv[1])
```

I used the python `sys` library which supports Command Line Arguments.

Command line arguments in python works similar to that in the C language.

> `sys.argv[0]` - holds the program's(script) name (in this case - "script.py")
>
> `sys.argv[1]` - holds the first argument
>
> `sys.argv[2]` - holds the second argument
>
> ... and so on

And here's its output :
[image]

Comment: now say the program needed to go on different computers that didnt hvw python, if i made it into a exe, would it still function the same way? as wll in your example how can i put 2 arguments into startinfo.arguments

Comment: If you build an executable, simply replace 'script.py' with the executable's filename. To pass more than one argument, simply separate them with spaces i.e `'arg1 arg2'`.

Comment: so i actually figured out how to add two arguments but i have run into a new problem. I am transferring a file location to python from VB. tis file location can have a space in it and since the command line looks for spaces, it takes what comes after the first space as a new argument

Comment: I, well am actually just "reading" your comment now. You should group the parameters with columns before passing them to python. You probably would've figured that out by now.